# Solving equation. Counting (x,y)

Tags: c++, c, math, equation-solving

I'm having a trouble with my math:

Assume that we have a function: F(x,y) = P; And my question is: what would be the most efficient way of counting up suitable (x,y) plots for this function ? It means that I don't need the coordinates themself, but I need a **number** of them. P is in a range: [0 ; 10^14]. "x" and "y" are integers. Is it solved using bruteforce or there are some advanced tricks(math / programming language(C,C++)) to solve this fast enough ?

To be more concrete, the function is: x*y - ((x+y)/2) + 1.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to count the number of integer solutions to *F(x,y) = P* for some fixed *P*?

Comment: Do you want to solve F(x,y) = <some constant>, or do you just want to plot it, automatically findint a suitable range?

Comment: C or C++ - I still dont know what to use. Depends if C++ has any special techniques, that can simplify the problem. If not - no reason for using it.

Comment: Neither C nor C++ has any built-in help for solving Diophantine equations, so you'll need to apply some mathematical reasoning. A very simple observation: your equation factorizes to `(x - 1/2) * (y - 1/2) == P - 3/4`, so even if you do need to brute-force, you only have to do so in one of the variables. Obviously, though, you can only truly brute force over the limited range of an integer type in your chosen language, not over all integers.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. This is a great observation!

Comment: @Steve put that has an answer!

Comment: @Ólafur: all right then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`x*y - ((x+y)/2) + 1 == P` is equivalent to `(2x-1)(2y-1) == (4P-3)`.

So, you're basically looking for the number of factorizations of `4P-3`. How to factor a number in C or C++ is probably a different question, but each factorization yields a solution to the original equation. [Edit: in fact two solutions, since if `A*B == C` then of course `(-A)*(-B) == C` also].

As far as the programming languages C and C++ are concerned, just make sure you use a type that's big enough to contain `4 * 10^14`. `int` won't do, so try `long long`.

Comment: IMO it is almost complete solution. +1 (@Dmitri: Why don't you mark this answer as the right one?)

Comment: These two answers both seem to be right, atleast for me :) I will take look at both of them.

Answer (score 2):

You have a two-parameter function and want to solve it for a given constant.

This is a pretty big field in mathematics, and there are probably dozens of algorithms of solving your equation.  One key idea that many use is the fact that if you find a point where `F<P` and then a point `F>P`, then *somewhere* between these two points, F must equal P.

One of the most basic algorithms for finding a root (or zero, which you of course can convert to by taking F'=F-P) is [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).  I suggest you start with that and read your way up to more advanced algorithms.  This is a farily large field of study, so happy reading!

Wikipedia has a list of [root-finding algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aRoot-finding_algorithms) that you can use as a starting place.

Comment: Newton's method and most other root-finding algorithms aren't really focused on integer-valued functions, but of course you can still use many them (for instance, simply solve the floating-point equation, then round the solution to integer, try if it is still a solution for the integer equation, if not try the adjacent values and so on).

Comment: The "key idea" assumes a functions that's continuous. A classic counterexample is `y=1/x`. There's no point where y=0, even though y=-1 at x=-1 and y=+1 at x=+1.

Comment: IMO this answer has almost nothing to do with the original question. The fact that `x, y` are integers matters very much.

Comment: @MSalters: Take any _constant_ C, then even for y=1/x you can find a value for y=C, but singularities are special, yes.

Comment: @Serge: He asks how to plot them, a very general question, not how to solve Diophantine equations.